# How to indent list items from the bullet?

Tags: html, list, css

I have a list item with a bullet in it added via CSS. The problem is, the text wraps under each bullet and I cannot seem to style it with text-indent. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wDL5/

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

li:before {
    content:"·";
    font-size:120px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a custom `list-style-image` instead ? So much simpler : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use positioning for the `:before` and list items:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    content:"·";
    font-size:120px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

#### Preview:

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/4wDL5/778/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ul
{
list-style-position:inside;
}
```

[See demo on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_list-style-position&preval=inside)

Comment: **Do not refer to W3Schools!** Check [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) for more info!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
li {
  font-size: 20px;

 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4wDL5/781/)

Comment: Can you explain what is `none outside none`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4wDL5/780/)

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
margin-left: 50px;
}

li:before {
    content:"·";
    font-size:120px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:20px;
position: absolute;
left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A really quick fix.

Add padding-left: 40px to your li

Add margin-left: -40px to your li:before

```
    li {
       list-style: none;
       font-size: 20px;
       padding-left: 40px;
    }

    li:before {
        content:"·";
        font-size:120px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        line-height:20px;
        margin-left: -40px;
    }
```